# How can I remove the underscore next to the image?

Tags: html, css, image

Given is the following page (SSCCE, just like we all like it):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    * {
        border:0;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    body {
        background:#BCD5E1;
        font:.85em Verdana;
    }

    #flag_panel {
        position:absolute;
        right:15px;
        top:20px;
    }

    #flag_panel img {
        vertical-align:middle;
    }

    #flag_panel .selected_image {
        border:solid 2px #444;
        padding:5px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="flag_panel">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="ro.gif" />
        </a>
        <img class="selected_image" src="us.gif" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This HTML file together with the 2 images can be found at the URL: [image-problem.zip](http://www.2shared.com/file/NlfkumEe/image-problem.html) (1.6 KB)

The expected result is:

[image: expected result]

But the actual result is:

[image: actual result]

As you can see, there's a little underscore between the 2 images. And I can't figure out why.

I tried this code in Firefox v24 and in Chrome v31. So I'm pretty sure I'm the one missing something.

I noticed that this problem goes away in 2 situations:

- if the `<img class="selected_image"...` comes before `<a href="#"...` (a.k.a. if they're swapped)
- if the first image is NOT enclosed inside an achor tag (`<a>`).

The goal of this piece of code is to be able to switch languages between English and Romanian on a site that I own. So one of the images must always have that border around it and the other must always be clickable. But I want to be able to do this without that underscore appearing there (looks ugly / buggy).

Any ideas on how to solve this ? Thanks.

Comment: Make a Fiddle please nobody wants to download files.

Comment: just remove the `text-decoration` from the anchor tag

Comment: @RaduMurzea A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or more simply a working demo that can be referenced later.

Comment: XD holly men 3K of repu and you don't know what is jsFiddle?

Comment: @Danko Sorry, I never asked questions about HTML/CSS before. But that site looks awesome, so thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the below in your code

```
#flag_panel a {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Because you are using, so white space is the issue there

```
<a href="#">
   <img src="#" />
</a>
```

So that's nothing but default `text-decoration`

---

Generally you should use the below snippet in your CSS

```
a {
   text-decoration: none; /* Gets rid of dirty default underline */
}
```

> Note: The above is an element selector, will select all `a` elements
>   in the document, but this is a general approach so thought I should
>   share one..

---

Also, I just went through your profile and I saw that you are not that friendly with HTML and CSS, so here's a tip for you, use [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) stylesheet, it will save your time when dealing with cross browser inconsistencies ... Or if you are not that worried about.. than use the below snippet in your CSS..

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   outline: 0;
}
```

The above selector simply selects all the elements in your document and gets rid of all the default `margin` and `padding` of the elements which are applied by the browser default stylesheet.

Comment: @RaduMurzea you welcome, just edited my answer, do read the tip.. :)

Answer (score 6):

Put the a tag element and its content on one line, like: `<a href="#"><img src="ro.gif" /></a>`

**EDIT:**

The `text-decoration: none;` approach still leaves you with a clickable white space.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is with `text-decoration` property that for default is `underline` in `a` tags. Just add this to the CSS:

```
a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/XF2qL/6/**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but closing the outer **div** is missing?

Comment: Sorry, the `div` was a `p` before, I forgot to change it